# How does the Linux 3.10.105 kernel handle Ethernet broadcast storms?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, ethernet, broadcast

In my embedded Linux device I want to find the source of Ethernet broadcast storm and flash the led once I detected the ethernet broadcast storm.

Does Linux kernel handle broadcast storms?

Is there any kernel device driver API's that I can use to detect the broadcast storm?

Comment: Pretty much doubt it. In my previous job, I used to detect those monitoring huge volume of ARPs and storing in a DB error statistics of all the switch ports of our organization.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, If not then I need to write such functionality so that I can identify broadcast storm, hope it's not complex to do that using Linux device driver.

Comment: I doubt you do such detection at the device driver level. I did not.